# User Data Deleted whenever Emulator Started in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, emulation

I am working with a small Android Application. I saved all the user data by creating my own sqlite database and tables in it. The Application runs fine on emulator. I was able to see all the data on DDMS. The next day when I start my Application and run it, on DDMS, I dont find my database. I observed that all my user data was wiped out. Don't know how this happened.

Can anyone please suggest me the solution for this. I want to retain my database till I delete or uninstall my Application.

Help will be appreciated. Please Help!!

Comment: Have you changed your emulator?

Comment: No. I was using the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should not wipe the user data while starting the emulator. check the below image [image]

uncheck the wipe user data and then launchu your emulator, it will maintain the user data.

Comment: I see that Option was already unchecked in my emulator. So, not able to understand why this happened.

Comment: while launching emulator, whether all the application are remain same as in previous days or only database are removed??

Comment: Application remains the same. Only database is being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You must have started a new emulator..are you it was the same instance of the emulator in which you saw those data?

Comment: I was using the same emulator through out my application.

Answer (score 0):

close your emulator processes, then check for *.lock files in c:\Users\%UserName%\.android\avd\{Your emulator name}\(in Windows, or where your emulator image is placed), If *.lock files present there, then delete them, and restart emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 with the Android 5.1.1 API's.  If the application crashes, etc you need to find the .lock files and delete them with the emulator off.  Then restart.  Sometimes they seem to stay even without a crash, just when powering down.  I would commented, but it wouldn't let me.